# Customizing infowindow on GWT

Tags: java, gwt, customization, infowindow

I am trying to customize a infowindow that I am using on GWT.  I am coding with Java and am not sure how to get all of the infowindow options.  Is it possible to do this in java or do I have to use javascript to get the options?  If so, I am not familiar with how to utilize javascript when I have everything implemented in java.

Comment: Please be more specific. What doesn't work for you? What have you done so far? Are you talking about the google maps api?

Comment: Hi sorry, yes I'm using google maps api, version 3.  I am trying to use InfoWindowOptions, but that only provides me with position type of customization and I was looking more for style, setting title, etc.